# What kind of Hat is Jimmy Rushing using in this photo?

Tags: jazz

Here is a pic I found of Count Basie and Jimmy Rushing. Does anybody know what is the name of the hat Jimmy Rushing is using?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a pork pie hat. Standard issue headwear in 50s jazz. As per Mingus' ["Goodbye Pork Pie Hat"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodbye_Pork_Pie_Hat)